# SQL Server 2005 : Incorrect syntax near '='

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, syntax-error

Did any body face above error in SQL Server 2005 when using `+=` string concatenation operator.

According to SQL Server 2005 books online, it should work, even the example shown in MSDN does not compile in SQL Server Management Studio 2005.

In SQL server 2008 it works fine.

I think its bug in SQL Server 2005.

The workaround is achieve the concatenation using `+` operator.

Comment: Show the code where this error occurs.

Comment: Never used that, but if MSDN said it works then I doubt it works in a SELECT statement. Maybe in a SET statement, but I don't think it works at all

Comment: Where's your link to it? I can only find [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd206992.aspx) which is for 2012, and the drop-down for other versions only lists "SQL Server 2008" and "SQL Server 2008 R2"

Comment: Try the code below guys,      DECLARE v1 varchar(40);
    SET v1 = 'This is the original.';
    SET v1 += ' More text.';
    PRINT v1;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The use of the c-like short assigment operators like `+=`, `-=` etc. is only valid from SQL Server 2008 onward. You can't use it with SQL Server 2005.

Comment: you are right! They are not there until SQL server 2008, check the version combo in link below, it does not include Server 2005, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645922

Answer (score 5):

It is not a bug, the augmented operators weren't implemented until SQL Server 2008